# Swfobject video doesn't work in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, swfobject

I have such swfoject that shows video in my site. It works fine at all browsers except IE 9. What can be the problem?

```
<script src='http://...js/swfobject.js'></script>
                    <div id='video' style='width: 640px; height: 480px;'></div>
                    <script >
                      swfobject.embedSWF('http://...js/swfobject.js', 'video', 640, 480, '10.3', 'false',
                        {file:'cam210.0', streamer:'rtmp://1111111111.../1111111111', 'rtmp.tunneling':false, autostart:true}, 
                        {allowFullScreen : 'true', allowNetworking : 'all'});
                    </script>
```

**UPDATE**

```
                <iframe id='video' name='iframeanimfx' src='http://xmpp.feelinhome.ru:8080/flu/js/swfobject.js'  height='600' width='900'></iframe>
                <script >

                 swfobject.embedSWF('http://...jwplayer.swf', 'video', 640, 480, '10.3', 'false',
                    {file:'cam210.0', streamer:'rtmp://.../1111111111', 'rtmp.tunneling':false, autostart:true}, 
                    {allowFullScreen : 'true', allowNetworking : 'all'});
                </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting it in an iframe,

```
<iframe name="iframeanimfx" src="http://yourswfobjecturl.swf"  height="600" width="900">
</iframe>
```

You can set the height and width of the iframe to whatever you like.

Comment: Well, if I put it in Iframe. It's like a lot of js code instead of video. What should I put in Iframe?

Comment: Should I put iframe instead of div?

Comment: Updated my post. It works fine in all browsers but like white window in IE

Comment: Oh sorry hold on I misread your response. Maybe try to download flash plugin for the other browsers

Comment: sure I'll do it if it helps)

Comment: thanks for upvote! Sorry to bother you more but could you please mark as correct so that it gets a green tick?

Comment: Ok, I marked it. Will you help me if I still have question or I should create new post?

Comment: Thanks! Will do what I can but maybe it's better to create a new post since stackoverflow says to avoid extended discussions in comments

Comment: Works fine, problem was at player.